# Angular2 application not working in Play framework

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.3

Below, the Angular related code is from Joost'g code. I think Joost used Activator. As I am using IntelliJ, I had to make some changes. In summary, my Angular2 application isn't working on IntelliJ and Play framework 2.6.x.

Steps:

- I have downloaded Scala started project from Play's website (2.6.x version)

  https://www.playframework.com/download
- I extracted the zip and executed sbt run

  ```
  C:\...\play-scala-starter-example>sbt run
  ```
- I verified that the application is running OK on localhost:9000.
- Then I imported the project in IntelliJ. I got a message that `Info: SBT compilation for play framework 2.x disabled by default`. **Question 1** - I do not understand what it implies.
- I built and ran the project in IntelliJ to check the project is stilling running OK (selected Edit Configuration option as Play 2 app). It was.
- I added an `assets` folder in `app` folder with following Angular2 related files (most files are from joost-de-vries project. I modified them a bit to compile the code).

1) assets\app folder which has 3 files - app.component.ts, app.module.ts, main.ts

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-root',
    template: `
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      `
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Tour of Heroes';
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

2) assets\systemjs.config.js file

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'assets/lib/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': 'assets/app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:angular__core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:angular__common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:angular__compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:angular__platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:angular__platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:angular__http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:angular__router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:angular__forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                meta: {
                    './*.js': {
                        loader: 'assets/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                    }
                }
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

3) assets\systemjs-angular-loader.js file

```
var templateUrlRegex = /templateUrl\s*:(\s*['"`](.*?)['"`]\s*)/gm;
var stylesRegex = /styleUrls *:(\s*\[[^\]]*?\])/g;
var stringRegex = /(['`"])((?:[^\\]\\\1|.)*?)\1/g;

module.exports.translate = function(load){
    if (load.source.indexOf('moduleId') != -1) return load;

    var url = document.createElement('a');
    url.href = load.address;

    var basePathParts = url.pathname.split('/');

    basePathParts.pop();
    var basePath = basePathParts.join('/');

    var baseHref = document.createElement('a');
    baseHref.href = this.baseURL;
    baseHref = baseHref.pathname;

    if (!baseHref.startsWith('/base/')) { // it is not karma
        basePath = basePath.replace(baseHref, '');
    }

    load.source = load.source
        .replace(templateUrlRegex, function(match, quote, url){
            var resolvedUrl = url;

            if (url.startsWith('.')) {
                resolvedUrl = basePath + url.substr(1);
            }

            return 'templateUrl: "' + resolvedUrl + '"';
        })
        .replace(stylesRegex, function(match, relativeUrls) {
            var urls = [];

            while ((match = stringRegex.exec(relativeUrls)) !== null) {
                if (match[2].startsWith('.')) {
                    urls.push('"' + basePath + match[2].substr(1) + '"');
                } else {
                    urls.push('"' + match[2] + '"');
                }
            }

            return "styleUrls: [" + urls.join(', ') + "]";
        });

    return load;
};
```

Changed build.sbt to following (again credit to Joost)

```
name := """play-scala-starter-example"""
version := "0.2.2"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
incOptions := incOptions.value.withNameHashing(true)
updateOptions := updateOptions.value.withCachedResolution(cachedResoluton = true)

//we use nodejs to make our typescript build as fast as possible
JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.jcenterRepo,
  Resolver.bintrayRepo("webjars","maven")
)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val ngVersion="4.2.5"
  Seq(
    guice,
    ehcache,

    "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.1",

    //angular2 dependencies
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__common" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__compiler" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__core" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__http" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__forms" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__router" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__platform-browser-dynamic" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "angular__platform-browser" % ngVersion,
    "org.webjars.npm" % "systemjs" % "0.20.14",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "rxjs" % "5.4.2",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "reflect-metadata" % "0.1.8",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "zone.js" % "0.8.4",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "core-js" % "2.4.1",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "symbol-observable" % "1.0.1",

    "org.webjars.npm" % "typescript" % "2.4.1",

    //tslint dependency
    "org.webjars.npm" % "tslint-eslint-rules" % "3.4.0",
    "org.webjars.npm" % "tslint-microsoft-contrib" % "4.0.0"
    //"org.webjars.npm" % "codelyzer" % "3.1.1"
    //"org.webjars.npm" % "types__jasmine" % "2.5.53" % "test"
    //test
    //"org.webjars.npm" % "jasmine-core" % "2.6.4"
  )
}
dependencyOverrides += "org.webjars.npm" % "minimatch" % "3.0.0"

// use the webjars npm directory (target/web/node_modules ) for resolution of module imports of angular2/core etc
//resolveFromWebjarsNodeModulesDir := true

// compile our tests as commonjs instead of systemjs modules
//(projectTestFile in typescript) := Some("tsconfig.test.json")

// use the combined tslint and eslint rules plus ng2 lint rules
//(rulesDirectories in tslint) := Some(List(
//  tslintEslintRulesDir.value,
//  ng2LintRulesDir.value
//))

// the naming conventions of our test files
//jasmineFilter in jasmine := GlobFilter("*Test.js") | GlobFilter("*Spec.js") | GlobFilter("*.spec.js")
//logLevel in jasmine := Level.Info
//logLevel in tslint := Level.Info
```

Added tsconfig.json

```
{
  /* the configuration of the typescript compiler. See docs https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options
  The settings outDir and rootDir are managed by sbt-typescript.
  */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    /* the following two settings are required for angular2 annotations to work*/
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators":true,
    /* for reading your ts source while debugging from a browser */
    "sourceMap": true,
    "mapRoot": "/assets",
    "sourceRoot": "/assets",
    "rootDirs": ["app/assets","test/assets"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "target/web/node-modules/main/webjars/*",
        "target/web/node-modules/test/webjars/*"
      ]
    },
    /* noImplicitAny when you want your typescript to be fully typed */
    "strict":true,
    "strictNullChecks":false, //doesn't work yet with @angular RC4
    "outDir": "./target/ts",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["target/web/node-modules/main/webjars/@types","target/web/node-modules/test/webjars/@types"]
  }
  /* the information below is not used by sbt-typescript. but you can use it if you want to run tsc -p .*/

}
```

Added tslint.json

```
{
  "lintOptions": {
    "fix": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-console": false,

    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [true, "rxjs"],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"],
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],


//    "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "my", "camelCase"],
//    "component-selector": [true, "element", "my", "kebab-case"],
//    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
//    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
//    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
//    "no-input-rename": true,
//    "no-output-rename": true,
//    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
//    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
//    "component-class-suffix": true,
//    "directive-class-suffix": true,
//    "no-access-missing-member": true,
//    "templates-use-public": true,
//    "invoke-injectable": true,


    "no-empty": true

  }
}
```

Then I added option to compile Typescript in Edit Configurations (I modified the Play2 App edit configuration I had used earlier)

I then added Application.scala controller  (credit Joost)

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

class Application extends InjectedController {

  def index = Action {

    Ok(views.html.index1())
  }
}
```

Then I added index1.scala.html

```
@()
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="angular2">
    <head>
        <base href="/" />
        @* In this version of the application the typescript compilation is done by the play framework.
        The browser downloads .js files. *@
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular Tour of Heroes</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/core-js/client/shim.min.js")'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/zone.js/dist/zone.js")'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/systemjs/dist/system.src.js")'></script>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("systemjs.config.js")'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("assets/app/main.js")'></script>

        <!--script>
                System.import('assets/app/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-root>Loading....</my-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

In above code, I initially tried using

```
<script>
                System.import('assets/app/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

but Chrome browser kept complaining about security issues. So I thought to include the main.js directly which I assume would get created by typescript compiler. I suspect that I am making some mistake here.

Finally modified the routes file

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
```

The application isn't working. I see `Loading ....`. The error on browser console is that it couldn't find `http://localhost:9000/assets/assets/app/main.js`.

I can see that .js files are getting created in the target\ts\app\assets\app folder. **Question 2** - What am I doing wrong?

Comment: update - I manually created an app folder under public folder and copied the .js files (app.component.js, app.module.js and main.js in this folder. Now the error (cannot find main.js) is gone but I still do not see the Angular application. I see lots of errors in browser window - `Refused to load the font 'data:font/woff;base64,eLo4GBkcWhIzkkAqQkEggceHw5HFkM2VRZJFlYebR2MP5v3cDSu5GJwWUDW9xG1hQXAFAmKZU=' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Combining independent apps into dependent ones is often a bad idea. Your client and server architectures should be as separate as possible. Get your client app up and running in a static, client side only project, once you get it figured out, it will be easy to drop it into `index.scala.html`.

Comment: Thanks but your answer doesn't help my current situation.

Comment: It's not meant as an answer it's meant as a comment. I'm suggesting that you rethink your approach. Starter kits are very seductive and can get you up and running quickly but they tend to leave behind substantial technical debt and may result in a code base that is not well understood by its maintainers.

Comment: I want to make client using Angular2. Server is play framework and scala. I do not understand how to develop them separately.

Comment: They are already separate. There are two applications. They communicate by passing serialized messages. This is complicated and often confused but it's very to important understand that they are discreet.

Comment: So, to run these to applications (Angular Client) and Play framework, two separate web servers will be used (say server-a and Play's own server). The pages of client application will be served by server-a and the client app will send GET/POST messages to Play (web services, which would hit the controller code of play application). The play server will thus be view-less (no html).

Comment: Actually in production, you will most likely run them on the same server. The point is to develop them independently and think about them independently so you can do things like use the most expedient and effective tools for each, have different people work on front end and backend, or simply to clarify separation of tasks, concerns and responsibilities between the client and server.

Comment: If you have NodeJS installed, run `npm install -g lite-server` which installs a little http-server for local development that supports hot-reloading and has good defaults. Then just run it from your client code-directory. You can take this a step further and also install something like `npm:json-server` to develop against a stub REST API that is backed by a simple static file server while you wait for something on the backend to be fleshed out. I've done it both ways and I really find the separate way to be more productive, lead to better code, and allow you to better adopt the optimal tooling

Comment: Otherwise you can end up with a mess before you even get started. Like why is your SBT config messing with your JavaScript and TypeScript linter settings? Its purpose is to be the most awesome Scala build tool it can be. (If you were using ScalaJS, then I would not have said all of this, but you have two completely independent, orthogonal toolchains and are coupling them for no benefit and at great cost)